# Summing up eigenvectors corresponding to binned eigenvalues

Tags: matlab

I have a `linspace` vector in matlab, a vector of `eigenvalues` and a matrix of its corresponding `eigenvectors` which I've obtained from the `eig` command.

I histogram the eigenvalues using `hist(eigenvalues,linspace)`.

I would like to sum up all the eigenvectors corresponding to each histogram bin.

For example, bin 1 contains eigenvalues `w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4`. I would like to find `v_bin1 = v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + v_4` where `v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4` are corresponding eigenvalues for eigenvectors `w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4` respectively.

How would one go about doing this, keeping vectorization in mind?

Comment: To make it easier for someone to answer you, you should provide a simple, small, self contained example with data, set it up to the point you are stuck. This makes it easier for someone to use it to answer you. Otherwise, people will have to make up data. see http://sscce.org/

Comment: Are you positive that the eigenvalues are all real numbers? If they are possibly complex, this will get, well, complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have N eigenvalues, and the corresponding eigenvector matrix is V (where the columns are the eigenvectors), you need to create a matrix A such that:

- A has N columns
- Each row of 'A' has 1's in places corresponding to the eigenvalues you want to sum. I.e., A(i,[1 ,2]) = 1 if you want to sum the first and second eigenvectors.
- The number of rows in A is the number of outputs you are looking for (the number of bins).

The result of A*V' will be a matrix where each row is the sum of eigenvectors you are looking for.

I'll leave it to you to determine how to construct the matrix A from the `linspace` vector you have. This may require a simple loop.